# Trying to git clone via SSH but getting broken pipe error

Tags: git

I am having some strange issues trying to `git clone` one of my public GitHub repositories because of a weird issue. I know it's not an issue with my key, because I've taken the same key from another VM and just simply fixed its permissions. This is the error that I get when trying to use SSH:

```
[root:kali:~/scripts]# ssh -T git@github.compacket_write_wait:
Connection to 192.30.253.112 port 22: Broken pipe
```

**Suggestion 1**

Reference: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/129

Tried to add the following to an `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 120
TCPKeepAlive no
```

and no luck. I've even tried changing `TCPKeepAlive` to `yes`, and the same thing happens.

My DNS server is set to `8.8.8.8`, so not quite sure that's the issue. I can git clone the http URL, just not the SSH URL.

**Suggestion 2**

I also tried to run the `ssh` command with the verbose option, and according to the output, it looks like it actually authenticates successfully, as shown below:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.253.113]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = C.UTF-8
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.30.253.113 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Any idea what else could be going wrong here?

Comment: `ssh -T git@github.com` what says? It should show your identified login name (which is identified by your public key).

Comment: @peterh turned out to be my network connection for some very strange reason. thanks though!

Comment: This worked for me in the context of pushing my repo to github. I added *IPQoS=throughput* to ~/.ssh/config

Comment: In my case, I had to turn off my WiFi and turn it back on again. Rest of internet was working, including fast.com, but for some reason no GitHub operations were working.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I don't know who this guy is, but bless him! This worked for me: https://blog.bchoy.me/post/2018-09-11-vmware-ssh-bug/

Put this in your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
   ServerAliveInterval 600
   TCPKeepAlive yes
   IPQoS=throughput
```

He has a link to some discussion about the IPQoS parameter -- which fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how VMWare networking handles things, but here is info on QoS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service

Answer (score 49):

## The solution

@crunk1 had [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54004358/425458) for me, but I didn't need all of the settings he listed. Minimally, in `~/.ssh/config` I just had to set:

```
Host *
   IPQoS=throughput
```

## Info on `IPQoS`

That fixed my problem, but then all I wanted to know was what the heck `IPQoS` is. I couldn't find a simple explanation anywhere (this thread is the top hit for `ipqos` on SO), but there is at least some info out there.

- The [`ssh_config` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#IPQoS) describes the `IPQoS` option we set above, and lists all of its valid values.
- The [Debian docs describe troubleshooting a similar situation](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Resolution_with_IPQoS_0x00) to that of the OP. In their case, they recommend

  ```
  Host *
      IPQoS=0x00
  ```

as the fix. Not sure what the difference is.

- Finally, the [`openssh` specifications page](https://www.openssh.com/specs.html) lists has spec [RFC8325](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8325), which describes `QoS` (quality of service) in great detail. Not so simple, but from what I can glean the idea is that, on connection, modern versions of the `openssh` server will communicate a `ToS` (type of service), which somehow has to align with your client's `QoS` settings.

Comment: What about Windows OS?

Comment: The last part is incorrect. QoS sets a field in the IP header that communicates to routers which priority the packet should get compared to others, it has nothing to do with communication or agreement with the server. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service and the man page matching the values listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service#DSCP_and_ECN

Answer (score 8):

I had this same error on macOS 10.15.6. One weird twist was that I could work around the error by turning on my VPN. I saw some other people [who use AT&T fiber](https://github.community/t/fatal-early-eof-on-fetch-or-pull-network-dependent/3221/8) also having this problem.

The fix for me was to add this to ~./ssh/config

```
Host github.com
  IPQoS 0x00
```

Setting `IPQoS=throughput` did not work for me. Credit goes to [@tel](https://github.community/t/fatal-early-eof-on-fetch-or-pull-network-dependent/3221/7) for the fix.

Comment: yep, I have AT&T fiber and this fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

Nevermind. Switched the network interface from NAT to bridged mode and now all is well. Crazy.

Comment: It is really crazy, it should work on NAT as well. Maybe some tricky firewall configuration could exist on your kali or on your host system.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off your VPN. It works for me.

Comment: This works, but I would prefer not to turn off vpn, but rather solve this if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me, is switching to `port 443` when on Public-WiFi, the symptom is the same, but the cause is actually `port 22` being blocked.

try

```bash
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com`
# > Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
# > provide shell access.
```

If `ssh` works this way, but doesn't work without the 443, that's the issue.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

In short, either use `ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443` in your `git` lines, or add to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be because of the VPN only.
I faced this issue and realized that in my organization they are using Network Drive (NTFS) and I could see some VPN related files there.

It showed red(x) icon which indicates the connection was disconnected. When I clicked the drive, it automatically got connected.

Then when I cloned through git, it worked fine.